# que es lo que me falta. para que el resultado sea igual al del ejemplo

Tags: javascript

```
function armarTexto(arreglo){
    var resultado="";

    for (var i in arreglo){
           resultado+= "propiedad"+i+"->"+arreglo[i]+";";
    }
    return resultado;
}
```

**¿Cúal es el error?**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: qué es lo que quieres hacer exactamente? Podrías pasar un poco más de tu código de manera a poder realizar pruebas y ayudarte!

Comment: Estás concatenando texto y no agregando propiedades a un objeto como te piden. 
Mira este [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Trabajando_con_objectos) que explica como trabajar con objetos en javascript, entre otras cosas como agregar propiedades. Si tienes dudas, edita la pregunta con lo que hayas intentado adicionalmente.

Comment: mi codigo da como resultado lo que esta en la imagen parte derecha donde dice your Output. pero deberia salir como Expercted Output. segun entiendo debo hacer la inicializacion en uno. y eso es lo que nose como hacer. ya busque informacion, e intente de todo y nada

Answer (score 1):

Te pongo dos maneras de hacerlo:

- vía ES6 (nueva versión)
- vía ES5 (vieja versión)

**ES6**

En ES6 vino una característica llamada [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Funciones/parametros_rest) la cual te permite interpretar parámetros de una función como si fuese un array. En este ejemplo te muestro ésta característica, sin embargo, *puedes cambiarlo para pasar un array directamente*.

```js
function arrayToObjectStr (...data) {
  const obj = {};
  data.forEach((val, i) => {
   obj[`propiedad${i+1}`] = val;
  });
  let toStr = '';
  for (let [k, v] of Object.entries(obj)) {
   toStr += `${k}->${v};`;
  }
  return toStr;
}

if (Object.entries) {
  console.log(arrayToObjectStr(4, 8, 12, 15)); 
} else {
  console.warn('Lo siento, su navegador no soporta ES2015');          
}
```

**ES5**

Hacerlo en ES5 es muy parecido, además de ser -por el momento- cross browser.

```js
function arrayToObjectStr (data) {
  var obj = {};
  data.forEach(function (val, i) {
    obj['propiedad' + (i+1)] = val;
  });
  var toStr = '';
  for (var key in obj) {
    toStr += key + '->' + obj[key] + ';';
  }
  return toStr;
}

console.log(arrayToObjectStr([4, 8, 12, 15]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Según lo que preguntas debes hacer lo siguiente:

```
function armarTexto(arreglo)
{
   var resultado="";
   for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++){
       resultado+= "propiedad"+i+"->"+arreglo[i]+";";
    }
    return resultado;
}
```

Comment: Por lo que entiendo, quiere convertir el array en objeto `obj` y luego imprimirlo

Comment: Puede ser, la verdad que falta formular mejor la pregunta.. Pero es lo que pude entender, ya que con éste código se logra imprimir de la manera que se observa en la imagen..

Comment: Cuando no está claro lo que dice el OP, es mejor preguntale comentando el post, porque si se da una respuesta suponiendo, muchas veces no será lo que el OP espera.

Answer (score 0):

Modificando el `for` y haciendo un pequeño ajuste a la forma de imprimir la posición del arreglo se puede arreglar el problema:

```js
var arreglo = [4,3,2,1];
var resultado = "";
for (i = 1; i <= arreglo.length; i++){
  resultado += "propiedad" + i + "->" + arreglo[i - 1] +";";
}
alert(resultado);
```

Answer (score 0):

Segun le entiendo la funcion debe devolver un objeto, a mi me funciono con esto

```
var regresaObjeto = function (arreglo) {
    var result = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++) {
        result["Propieda" + (1 + i)] = arreglo[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```