# Calcular edad con un objeto constructor en Javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente problema:

¿Cómo calcular la edad de una persona con un objeto constructor que me falta?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
function calcularEdad(nombre, diaNacimiento, mesNacimiento, anioNacimiento) {
 var obj={
     nombre:nombre,
     diaNacimiento:diaNacimiento,
     mesNacimiento:mesNacimiento,
     anioNacimiento:anioNacimiento
 }

var fecha_hoy = new Date();
var ahora_ano = fecha_hoy.getYear();
var ahora_mes = fecha_hoy.getMonth();
var ahora_dia = fecha_hoy.getDate();
var edad = (ahora_ano + 1900) - ano;

if ( ahora_mes < ( - 1)){
  edad--;
}
if (((mesNacimiento - 1) == ahora_mes) && (ahora_dia < diaNacimiento)){ 
  edad--;
}
if (edad > 2017){
    edad -= 2017;
}

return "¡Tienes " + edad + " años!";
}
```

Comment: La [otra pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/43180/que-es-lo-que-me-falta-para-que-el-resultado-sea-igual-al-del-ejemplo) que hiciste, ¿se solucionó? Si es así, considera marcar la respuesta que consideres correcta.

Answer (score 1):

Haz tenido algunos fallos en las condiciones a la hora de calcular la edad y para recibir el valor de un objeto tienes que hacerle referencia, ej: `obj.nombre`

Tú código funcionando:

```js
function calcularEdad(nombre, diaNacimiento, mesNacimiento, anioNacimiento) {
  
  var obj = {
    nombre:nombre,
    diaNacimiento:diaNacimiento,
    mesNacimiento:mesNacimiento,
    anioNacimiento:anioNacimiento
  }

  var fecha_hoy = new Date();
  var ahora_ano = fecha_hoy.getFullYear();
  var ahora_mes = fecha_hoy.getMonth();
  var ahora_dia = fecha_hoy.getDate();
  
  var edad = ahora_ano - obj.anioNacimiento;
  
  if ( ahora_mes < (obj.mesNacimiento - 1)) {
    
    edad--;    
  }
    
  if (((obj.mesNacimiento - 1) == ahora_mes) && (ahora_dia < obj.diaNacimiento)) {
        
    edad--;
  }

  return obj.nombre + ", tienes " + edad + " años!";
}


alert(calcularEdad('Sammia', 28, 8, 1998));
```

Answer (score 0):

[obtener la edad (años, meses y días) a partir de la fecha de nacimiento con javascript](http://aandresdev.blogspot.pe/2017/01/obtener-la-edad-anos-meses-y-dias.html)

Función calcularEdad (años, meses y días)

```
function calcularEdad(fecha) {
        // Si la fecha es correcta, calculamos la edad

        if (typeof fecha != "string" && fecha && esNumero(fecha.getTime())) {
            fecha = formatDate(fecha, "yyyy-MM-dd");
        }

        var values = fecha.split("-");
        var dia = values[2];
        var mes = values[1];
        var ano = values[0];

        // cogemos los valores actuales
        var fecha_hoy = new Date();
        var ahora_ano = fecha_hoy.getYear();
        var ahora_mes = fecha_hoy.getMonth() + 1;
        var ahora_dia = fecha_hoy.getDate();

        // realizamos el calculo
        var edad = (ahora_ano + 1900) - ano;
        if (ahora_mes < mes) {
            edad--;
        }
        if ((mes == ahora_mes) && (ahora_dia < dia)) {
            edad--;
        }
        if (edad > 1900) {
            edad -= 1900;
        }

        // calculamos los meses
        var meses = 0;

        if (ahora_mes > mes && dia > ahora_dia)
            meses = ahora_mes - mes - 1;
        else if (ahora_mes > mes)
            meses = ahora_mes - mes
        if (ahora_mes < mes && dia < ahora_dia)
            meses = 12 - (mes - ahora_mes);
        else if (ahora_mes < mes)
            meses = 12 - (mes - ahora_mes + 1);
        if (ahora_mes == mes && dia > ahora_dia)
            meses = 11;

        // calculamos los dias
        var dias = 0;
        if (ahora_dia > dia)
            dias = ahora_dia - dia;
        if (ahora_dia < dia) {
            ultimoDiaMes = new Date(ahora_ano, ahora_mes - 1, 0);
            dias = ultimoDiaMes.getDate() - (dia - ahora_dia);
        }

        return edad + " años, " + meses + " meses y " + dias + " días";
    }
```

Función esNumero

```
 function esNumero(strNumber) {
        if (strNumber == null) return false;
        if (strNumber == undefined) return false;
        if (typeof strNumber === "number" && !isNaN(strNumber)) return true;
        if (strNumber == "") return false;
        if (strNumber === "") return false;
        var psInt, psFloat;
        psInt = parseInt(strNumber);
        psFloat = parseFloat(strNumber);
        return !isNaN(strNumber) && !isNaN(psFloat);
    }
```

Comment: Las respuestas deben ser autocontenidas. Si en el enlace al material externo has puesto una explicación demasiado amplia para este espacio, deberías indicar la más relevante aquí.